# Incorrect Date when using formatter->asDate() on Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Why do I keep getting incorrect result for some dates?

```
echo Yii::$app->formatter->asDate('1581-10-10', 'php: d M Y');
```

gives "30 Sep 1581". Looks like some dates far in the past will give several days of gap.

This is normal for recent dates.

Comment: This is just a wild guess but this might be caused by difference between Gregorian and Julian calendars. The Gregorian calendar is used since October 1582. The date `1581-10-10` in Gregorian calendar matches `1581-09-30` in Julian calendar.

Comment: @MichalHynčica that makes sense. Thank you for the explanation.